# how to implement color switcher for each image

Tags: cakephp, colors, switchers

I'm developing e-commerce website in cakephp 2.x, in which admin can upload many images and each image will have individual color. " Problem is how to give option to admin to choose color for each image."
like

```
image A has color black, 
Image B has color Blue, 
Image C has color grey
```

`echo $this->Form->input('Color');`  convert into drop down list to select color(Colors are saved in database). I'm confuse how to display drop down menu to admin against each image to select. if i use it multiple time  `$this->Form->input('Color');`   ,  it creates with same id and in controller only one color is received. if i use  $this->Form->input('Color',$i); to create drop down with different id then it not convert into drop down . it is just text field(because field name does not match and cakephp does not convert it into drop down list), so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in that case, put the dropdown options manually:

```
foreach($images as $key => $image) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Color.' . $key, array(
        'options' => $colors,
    ));
}
```